# GA4 BigQuery screen resolution

Tags: google-bigquery, screen-resolution, google-analytics-4

Is there something wrong with my setup on BigQuery for GA4 or can we not query for screen resolution anymore?

[image]

EDIT: My Query

```
SELECT 
(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) as date,
device.category as deviceCategory,
device.mobile_brand_name as mobileDeviceBranding,
device.mobile_model_name as mobilDeviceModel,
device.mobile_marketing_name as mobileDeviceMarketingName,
device.operating_system as OS,
device.operating_system_version as OSVersion,
device.web_info.browser as Browser,
device.web_info.browser_version as browserVersion,
device.screenresolution as screnRes,
user_id,
params1.value.string_value as clientType,
params2.value.string_value as userAgent,
 FROM `xxx` ,
 UNNEST(event_params) AS params1, UNNEST(event_params) AS params2
 WHERE (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date)) >= CURRENT_DATE()-30
 AND event_name = 'user_engagement'
AND (params1.key ='client_type' )
AND (params2.key ='user_agent' )
limit 500
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: Field name screenresolution does not exist in STRUCT<category STRING, mobile_brand_name STRING, mobile_model_name STRING, ...> at [11:8]

Comment: It seems Google don't even have it in their documentation :/ https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=9359001

But this is strange because on Data Studio you can extract it - just not on BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your GA4 BigQuery setup. I think it's an oversight from Google Analytics and they've neglected to include the screen resolution in the GA4 BigQuery export. (I'm chalking it up as yet another 'quirk' of GA4 that's reflective of it not truly being 'production ready' yet). In my opinion, the screen resolution should be a device attribute that comes through in another 'device.*' column in the GA4 BigQuery export, but Google are yet to include it. The screen resolution is accessible from the GA4 UI (you should find it in the >Users >Tech >Tech overview section of the UI), but sadly it's seemingly not yet accessible from the GA4 BigQuery export data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add screen resolution from tag manger.
you create a custom JS variable with this code:

```
function() {
var width = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, 
window.innerWidth || 0);
var height = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, 
window.innerHeight || 0);
var dimensions = width + 'x' + height;
return dimensions;
}
```

then you push the variable to a field in the configuration tag, then it would be available for each event, unnest it from event_params.